# Icons clickable while content in a carousel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I just want to ask how can I make this icons clickable and after clicking it will go to the specified content and will work like carousel? I'm using bootstrap 3

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<div class="container">

            <div class="row text-center">

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Here's how kinectAPI works</h1>



                    <div id="create" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Create an account</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="define" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Define your App</h4>

                    </div>

                    <div id="sync" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Sync Local Client</h4>

                    </div>

                    <div id="cloud" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20" >
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Get data from the cloud</h4>

                    </div>

                    <div id="scale" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                        <h4>Scale as required</h4>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <!--<ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>-->

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <div class="item active col-lg-12">
                                 <!--<div class="col-lg-5"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-responsive"></div>-->
                                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <p>
                                    Sign up for a free account to get started. Your kinectAPI.com account creates dedicated space for your sensor data and applications on Windows Azure™. Within your account, you can define your applications, register your Kinect™ sensors, download the Local Client, and monitor the usage of data being created and accessed by your applications.
                                    </p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                 <!--<div class="col-lg-5"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-responsive"></div>-->
                                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <p>
                                    There’s a lot of raw data that is generated by the sensor, which is why kinectAPI pre-processes the raw data stream so that only what your application needs is uploaded to the cloud. You define what data in the raw stream your app needs in your kinectAPI account, either from selecting individual modules or by selecting from our pre-cooked definitions (e.g. “I need to detect Presence). This way, when your Local Client syncs with your kinectAPI account, the parts of the stream you need are uploaded for cloud access, and the rest is ignored.
                                    </p>                              
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                 <!--<div class="col-lg-5"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-responsive"></div>-->
                                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <p>
                                    The Local Client is a native Windows application running on the Appliance - which is what we call the PC that your sensor is connected to. The Local Client is logged into your kinectAPI account, and automatically reads what applications you have defined. From there, you simply select the app that you need the data for, and the Appliance starts to capture the appropriate data and send it to the cloud ready for it to be accessed via our API and consumed by your application. 
                                    </p>                              
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                 <!--<div class="col-lg-5"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-responsive"></div>-->
                                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <p>
                                    Once your Local Client is sending data to the cloud, accessing that data is as simple as writing RESTful API calls from your application.
                                    </p>                              
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                 <!--<div class="col-lg-5"><img src="//placehold.it/450x300" alt="folder" class="img-responsive"></div>-->
                                  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <p>
                                    It’s free to create your kinectAPI account! You’ll be given a basic level of cloud storage and API call limits to begin building your first application using kinectAPI, during which you’ll no doubt discover how easy it is to use. Once your application starts to push the quotas of your free account, you can easily upgrade to one of the paid options that will be available, giving you greater cloud storage and API call limits. If you’re building something BIG, you can always contact us and we can customise a package that meets your needs.
                                    </p>                              
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try some variations on a Carousel with thumbnails, you'll find some examples in:

http://www.bootply.com/

For instance:

- [Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider / Carousel](http://www.bootply.com/122291)
- http://www.bootply.com/102885

Comment: Hey, this helps. I'm trying it now :)

Comment: Thank you Roberto I have my icons working along with the content :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="path/to/destination">
  <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x m-t10"></i>
</a>
```

Put Your icons inside n "a" element